# Custom Statistics in TeamCity 6.0

Tags: teamcity

I am trying to follow this writeup (http://pwigle.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/code-metrics-statistics-with-team-city/) to add code statistics to my TeamCity 6.0 Ci server.  I have gotten everything to work as described in the writeup except the last part where the results of the SourceMonitor are displayed in the statistics page.  Is there something different that I need to do in TeamCity 6.0 to get this to work?

Comment: I'm in the same position now, can't get the graphs to show.

Comment: Does my answer (posted below) not work for you?

Comment: Well I dont know exactly know as other graphs and charts are configured exactly as mentioned in the blog post so im scratching my head a little for TC 8 setups.

Comment: Would you posting what you have did to get it to work? Give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: What I did below works for 6...I can't comment on 8 as I have eliminated the custom graphs before I moved to 8

Comment: I would post your own question to try and get help with 8.  I am just using the built in items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI you have to edit (TeamCity path).BuildServer\config\main-config in 6.0 instead of (TeamCity path).BuildServer\config(project name)\plugin-settings.xml. The plugin-settings.xml file is still present in 6.0 but doesn’t appear to do anything anymore. After that all works as detailed in the write up I posted before.